# Issues with Concatenated SMS PDU

Tags: sms, gsm, pdu

I'm working with SMS and PDU's and creating concatenated messages to send with a GSM modem (Cinterion MC35i), but when I send the concatenated message, it never appears on the other side.  Here is a transcript of the comms with the modem:

```
at
OK
at+cmgf=0
OK
at+cmgs=153
> 0041B60A9174742906290000A1050003B60201A8E8F41CD42ECFE7E17319949E83CAF8F098CECE8362B618688C0ECBC3637A593E07B1DFEEB30B04A2A2CBA0783D3D5E83C4F2F7DD0D32BFF12075BD0D9F83DEF6B21C44479741ECB03E0F22BFCF2E10E8890691CB6139E88E0ED341E3B01B44479741ED309D5E9683C46517282C1E93CBE6333AAD5EB3DBEE373C2E9FD3EBF63B3EAF8FC96634
+CMGS: 108

OK
at+cmgs=25
> 0041B60A91747429062900000E050003B602026AB61B2E070B01
+CMGS: 109

OK
```

I've validated the PDUs using this [SMS PDU Decoder](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/online-sms-pdu-decoder/), yet the message never arrives.  I have also tried sending to another mobile phone, same result.  If I send a normal message (i.e. non concatenated PDU message), the message is received fine.  Mobile phones tested include HTC Desire Z and iPhone 4.

Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

TP-DA seems to be incorrect. Are you removing + ?

Replace 0A917474290629 by 0A817474290629 and check again.

Comment: Please do not add signatures to your posts - take a look at the [FAQ on signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). Also, I'd be wary of including links to your profile, as it can be viewed as spam when done in excess.

Comment: The "91" indicates that the number that follows conforms to International numbering plan.  Changing it to "81" will not work. See http://mobiletidings.com/2009/02/11/more-on-the-sms-pdu/ for more information about the formatting of TP-DA